# How to export a Swagger JSON/YAML file for selective endpoints?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, swagger

I want to share an endpoint with my client to generate the swagger YAML file which contains information of selective endpoints, I Don't want to share all endpoint details. I am using Spring MVC based application and I already have swagger implemented?

can someone please give me some idea, how we can achieve this? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Create a new document with only required Api's from existing all documented that containing all endpoints. This will be easy for you

Comment: @AshishKarn thanks for your suggestion Ashish but I also have to create a swagger UI page with selected endpoints.